# Failed to install Vaadin plugin for Spring Roo

Tags: spring-roo, vaadin

I've installed Spring Roo (1.2.0.RELEASE [rev 39eb957]), but I am failed to install Vaadin plugin. Here is the console output I got:

```
roo> pgp trust --keyId 0xBF0451C0
Added trust for key:
>>>> KEY ID: 0xBF0451C0 <<<<
     More Info: http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?fingerprint=on&op=index&s
earch=0xBF0451C0
     Created: 2009-??-14 11:54:20 +0000
     Fingerprint: cc57399d74cd7e4768ed6fa4ca62973fbf0451c0
     Algorithm: DSA
     User ID: Artur Signell <artur@vaadin.com>
          Signed By: Key 0xBF0451C0 (Artur Signell <artur@vaadin.com>)
     Subkey ID: 0x17EBEE72 [ELGAMAL_ENCRYPT]

roo> download accept terms of use
Thank you. All Spring Roo download features have now been enabled.

roo> addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName com.vaadin.spring.roo.addon
Unsatisfied requirement(s):
---------------------------
   (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.entity)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2
.0.0)))
      Vaadin Plug-in for Spring Roo

Unable to install add-on: Vaadin Plug-in for Spring Roo [version: 1.0.1]
```

It's seems a incompatible version problem, but I can't find the plugin of version 1.1.0 or 2.0.0. Could anyone help me?

Comment: After I switched back to Roo 1.1.5, the installation is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted yourself, it's a version incompatibility. The Vaadin plug-in is unfortunately currently only compatible with Roo 1.1.5

The team is currently very busy with Vaadin 7, but hopefully time will be allocated for the Vaadin Roo plug-in as well.